# Is any script executed on replacing HTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am replacing the content of my HTML DOM with jQuery like:

```
$('#identifier').html('<html-content>');
```

The `<html-content>` is loaded by an ajax request and included in the HTTP response. I do need to execute any `<script>` which is encluded in this HTML. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what... I'm confused.. what are you actually asking? Please include a minimal working example of the problem

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: Use `$.ajax()` and inside the `success` part, append the reply to your HTML dom element